# Is it possible to do a left outer join where something other than NULL fills the non-values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

Here's the problem. :(

A column of my table `Answers` which is like

```
               Answers
------------------------------------
 id | user_id | question_id |  ans
------------------------------------
 1  |    1    |     1       |   0
 2  |    1    |     2       |  85
 3  |    2    |     1       |   5
 4  |    2    |     2       | NULL
```

where the value of `ans` are in the range

```
NULL, 0, 5, ..., 95, 100
```

and `NULL` means the user has answered and chosen "no answer", effectively. However, when I `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the `Questions` table with the `Answers` I can't distinguish between a question that hasn't been answered an a question that has been answered with "no answer".

So is there a way that I can do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that fills in the non-values with `-1` instead of `NULL`?

(I like to think I'm not a crappy database designer ... the problem is that the requirements of my project keep get changed late in the cycle. The requirements are like a moving target.)

Comment: If there's complete data available, why is it `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Can you show us the query?

Comment: NULL is not a value.  It's a marker indicating that no value is present.

Comment: @WalterMitty It is much more helpful to say that NULL is a value that is treated specially by operators. (The SQL standard actually calls NULL a "special value".) First because it's simple, precise & true, second because explaining what "marking" is comes down to that and 3rd because the operators do not actually behave as if a NULL in a table indicated that no value is present. Ie the ways that the operators treat it specially cannot reasonably be said to give results as if no value is present--whether by "not present" you mean column not applicable or value unknown. That ambiguity being 4th.

Comment: With regard to "true", I take the relational model as closer to truth than the SQL model.  Well, even CJ Date and Ed Codd don't quite agree on whether the absence of a value is a special value.  With regard to "helpful", I think that SQL's three valued logic is terribly difficult to explain, unless you give a detailed explanation of what "special value" implies in this context.  Is NULL equal to NULL or is it not?

Comment: As far as this particular case is concerned, the key is in the OP.  NULL means that the user has chosen "no answer".  This means we know that the answer is not 0, 5,..., 95, 100.  That's different from what NULL often means.  In particular, it's different from what NULL means when generated by a left outer join.

Comment: @WalterMitty Re "precise & true", I just meant that "NULL is a value that is treated specially by operators" precisely expresses a truth about SQL. (Using "special" in its everyday sense.) That is normal language: operators map values to values. What is also precise & true is that a row (...,*ans*) goes in the table if and only if (using 2VL with NULL a value) "... AND *ans* is the answer given OR ... AND *ans* IS NULL AND no answer was given" . Saying NULL "marks" or "indicates" something that "means" something like "absence" is informal, vague and begs explanation. Hence my "unhelpful".

Comment: Data without meaning is of no value. The semantics of data is a separate study from its structure and the operations on it, to be sure  But it is far from "informal".  Except in environments where the custodians of the data have nothing to do with its meaning.

Comment: Wikipedia, among other references, specifically describes the SQL NULL as a marker indicating a missing value.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)  so did the textbooks I studied years ago.

Comment: @WalterMitty Re "The semantics of data is a separate study from its structure and the operations on it" On the contrary, it is fundamental to the relational model that relation operator output tables have meanings formed from the meanings of input tables. It is straightforward, clear & normal to talk about how operators & consequent meanings use values. Whereas "NULL is a marker" begs a complex justification and "NULL is not a value" & "data is missing" are doublespeak. That wiki article is a good example of such confused writing. Eg "SQL null is a state (unknown) and not a value." Nonsense.

Comment: We can agree to disagree, and let it rest there.  In the meantime, the most helpful thing for the OP will be to help him come up with a design that serves his needs better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  One method uses a `case` statement:

```
select a.*, (case when a.id is not null then coalesce(ans, -1) end) as ans
from b left join
     a
     on b.answerid = a.id;
```

I just made up the `join` conditions and columns.  The key is to use the join key to determine if there is a record match.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check the existence of a not-nullable column in the answers table, like this:

```
select ..., case when answers.ans is not null then answers.ans 
                 when answers.id is not null then -1 
                 else null 
            end
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, when there is a successful match to `LEFT JOIN` on, there's some column in that table (a key you're joining on) that isn't null.  Your query could be refactored to look something like:

```
SELECT q.question_id
    ,q.question
    ,CASE WHEN a.question_id IS NOT NULL 
          THEN COALESCE(a.ans, -1)
     END as ans
FROM question q
LEFT JOIN answer a
ON q.question_id = a.question_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much control you have over the data as given.  It's unfortunate that NULL was chosen to represent an answer that the user gave, namely "no answer".  This makes it very, very difficult to distinguish between a NULL that was generated by the user, and one that was generated by a left outer join operation.  It might be good if the database defined a special value, like say, -1, to represent "user specified no answer", and let NULL stand for "missing value" and nothing else.
Using -1 as a special value will lead to some convoluted logic in your queries, but it's not as bad as the mess you are in now.

PS:  This doesn't mean your'e a bad database designer.  It just means that database design is sometimes more subtle than we think.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick that would work, but it is subtle and would require good documentation so developers will be aware of it.

```
select  u.UserName, q.Question_ID Asked, a.Question_ID Answered, a.Ans
from    Users u
join    Questions q
    on  q.User_ID = u.User_ID
left join Answers a
    on  a.User_ID = u.User_ID
    and a.Question_ID = q.Question_ID
[order by ...];
```

Notice that I'm calling out the Question_ID from both the Questions and Answers table rather than the Questions table alone. This means that when there is a question a user has not answered at all, both Answered and Ans will be NULL. If the user has answered the question with "no answer", then only Ans will be null. The Asked column will, of course, never be null.

```
UserName   Asked  Answered   Ans
========   =====  ========   ======
Sam        17     17         True      ==> Answer to Q17 is "True"
Sam        18     18         NULL      ==> Answer to Q18 is "no answer"
Sam        19     NULL       NULL      ==> Q19 has not been answered
```

A little logic in the app can easily handle this. If you are not interested in questions that have not yet been answered, add the following to the query:

```
where   a.Question_ID is not null
```

Thus a NULL in Ans would *only* mean "no answer"...but you have effectively turned the outer join into an inner join so you could more easily write it like that. I take it then that you *are* interested in seeing all the questions and want to distinguish "no answer" from *not answered*.

Answer (score -3):

select ..., isnull(ans, -1)

If this is not what you are looking for then post your select statement

Comment: Down vote based on the stated question that may be all they need

Comment: This would cause false positives - `ans` might be null because it really is null, or because the question had no record

Comment: Until we see the query it is speculation.

Comment: I think this part makes it pretty clear: `and NULL means the user has answered and chosen "no answer", effectively. However, when I LEFT OUTER JOIN the Questions table with the Answers I can't distinguish between a question that hasn't been answered an a question that has been answered with "no answer".`

Comment: OK, Dan - let's not make a federal case out of it.  I would like to see the actual query.